# Display Each Row Where URL Variable Corresponds With Database ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a URL that is dynamically generated:

https://mywebsite.co.uk/report.php?taskid=25&rep=1&rep=2&rep=3

I can retrieve the variable for the task ID and rep fine:

```
if (isset($_GET['taskid'])) { $taskid = $_GET['taskid']; }
if (isset($_GET['rep'])) { $referenceID = $_GET['rep']; }
```

What I'm trying to do is create an SQL statement on the page that selects a row based on the rep number in the URL.  For example:

```
SELECT TASK_ID, ID, NAME FROM mytable WHERE TASK_ID = $taskid AND ID = $referenceID
```

However, when I echo the result of $referenceID it is always the last rep, so in this case 3.  How do I select the rows from the database where ID = 1,2 & 3?

I then want to display each row, so it would be something like:

```
<table>
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TASK_ID, ID, NAME FROM mytable WHERE TASK_ID = $taskid AND ID = $referenceID");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$ID = $row['ID'];
$NAME = $row['NAME'];
print "<tr><td>$ID</td><td>$NAME</td></tr>";
}
</table>
```

This query should return 3 rows in the table with the ID AND NAME in each row.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use array-style URL parameters?

Comment: if you use same index 'rep' then it will override every time and only get last value... do not use this link ,
it is recommend to use POST method

Comment: You can not use same index for different values, have to different index for each parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to change your parameter name from rep to rep[]
This will cause PHP $_GET['rep'] to return an array.

Then you need to implode the array to obtain a string with commas:

```
if (isset($_GET['rep'])) { 
    $referenceID = implode(',',$_GET['rep']); 
}
```

You have to change your SQL syntax to this:

```
SELECT TASK_ID, ID, NAME FROM mytable WHERE TASK_ID = $taskid AND ID IN ($referenceID)
```

Comment: This solution is subject to SQL injection. You need to escape the reps, as in my answer.

Comment: Strings are only sanitized if you use `bind_param`, not if you just use interpolation. The problem is that `bind_param` is hard to use when the number of parameters is variable.

Answer (score -1):

try  this query

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT TASK_ID, ID, NAME FROM mytable WHERE TASK_ID = $taskid AND (ID <= $referenceID and ID>= 1)");
```

Comment: What if the IDs in the URL aren't in sequence from 1 to 3?

Answer (score -1):

You should use array-style URL parameters, e.g.

```
https://mywebsite.co.uk/report.php?taskid=25&rep%5B%5D=1&rep%5B%5D=2&rep%5B%5D=3
```

Then `$_GET['rep']` will be an array, and you can do:

```
$referenceIDs = implode(',', array_map(array($con, 'real_escape_string'), $_GET['rep']));
$sql = "SELECT TASK_ID, ID, NAME
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE TASK_ID = $taskid 
        AND ID IN ($referenceIDs)";
```

Comment: Why the silent downvotes? Is it because I used `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of a parametrized query? Parameters are hard to do when the number of parameters is variable.